# No speaker found while training speaker identification with MARF

Tags: java, voice-recognition

I'm getting an error while training using wav file

```
~/SpeakerIdentApp-bin-0.3.0-devel-20060226$ java -jar SpeakerIdentApp.jar --single-train testing-samples/1.wav
No speaker found for "testing-samples/1.wav" for training.
Done training with file "testing-samples/1.wav".
```

Can someone shed some light over the issue.

Comment: I guess you can shed some light on it. What where you trying to do. Which lib / program are you using. Maybe give some more information about the problem you have.

Comment: I'm using Modular Audio Recognition Framework. What I'm trying to do is to make a voice authorization app in j2se.

Comment: Well, if you are using this: http://marf.sourceforge.net/ then I would do two things:
1) Check this website for any help and support. Does not look to me as if that project is maintained very frequently
2) Consider using some other library. The software was last modified in 2007 I doubt that there is some active community around it.

Answer (score 1):

MARF training requires the names of the speakers to be present in 'speakers.txt' file which must be located in the root folder. In this file, you are required to enter all the speakers along with the filenames of their voice samples over which you want to train MARF. The format for 'speakers.txt' file is as follows:

SpeakerID, SpeakerName, Filename_1 | Filename_2 | ... | Filename_n

You can go through the website http://marf.sourceforge.net for documentation and download the speaker identification application along with the training data to get better insight on how to get it working.

I hope you find this useful.